# How to give a Path to Files/Folder in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, path, file-handling

```
string strFile;
strFile = "Reports/" + ReportName;

ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") + strFile);
```

My existing folder is Reports in Mvc in web...
When I run it locally it runs but when I publish to web it shows path not found..
The error I am getting is

> Could not find file 'C:\inetpub\test\Reports\rptA.rdlc'

and on my web Page

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Runtime Error

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the root path of the web site with [HostingEnvironment.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
strFile = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath,  "Reports/" + ReportName);
```

Comment: Did you debug, what value you get in strFile?

Comment: ya.. same issue.. after publish to web its not finding the path.. local working fine

Comment: "Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime Error"

Comment: Is it not giving error that you got earlier, could not find file on path C:\inetpub\test\Reports\rptA.rdlc

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `MVC` in your question but not in your tags so it becomes probably confusing.

I think you are using MVC

```
   string filepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/YorFolderName/YourFile"); (from MVC1 to MVC3)
```

or for **MVC4**

```
   string filepath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/YorFolderName/YourFile");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hey i am doing the Same thing.. Code is Published above... and its working Fine on my local machine... but when i go to publish it to web it Cannot Find its Path